# Joomla 3.0.3 installation gets stuck in the configuration section in Xubuntu 16.04 localhost

Tags: xubuntu, apache2, mysql, localhost, joomla

Trying to setup joomla 3.0.3 on my localhost on Xubuntu 16.04 but the installation gets stuck in the configuration section. After fulfilling all the tabs when I click next, it takes me back to the configuration again, tried 2.5, (3.45 dont even load the installation process) versions but results in same issue though drupal and wordpress is running fine. I have installed apache2 (ver 2.4.18), mysql-server (ver 5.7.12) and php7.0.

The error log I assume  http://paste.ubuntu.com/16830893/

The ls -la /etc/apache2/ result is http://paste.ubuntu.com/16902897/

Comment: Post the log so that we can help

Comment: How can I do that, the logs, where to be found?

Comment: Ajay Kulkarni, I have edited the question details.

Comment: `apache2ctl -V`  (or `apache -V`, or just `httpd -V`) then check HTTPD_ROOT and add DEFAULT_ERRORLOG, so if HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd" and DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log" then check /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

Comment: @PavelSayekat: Please do what Putnik suggested...

Comment: @Putnik: My HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2", and DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log", and there is no logs folder in /etc/apache2/ .

Comment: @PavelSayekat pls post `ls -la /etc/apache2/` (maybe better not to comment but to the main post)

Comment: @Putnik: edited the question details.

Comment: either wrong log or it is not an apache error. For example server may return 302 code and you'll found nothing in error_log.

If you have nobody nearby to dig the code then I'd kill it all and started from scratch.

ps: make sure site file permissions are ok. See chown and chmod commands.

Comment: And my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/16905674/

And /etc/apache2/sites-available/joomla.conf is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/16905723/

Comment: And the /var/log/apache2/error.log file link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxPYgHFVQ6LsZnVCeV9fMlpJNzQ/view?usp=sharing&pref=2&pli=1

Comment: @Putnik, I've done that few times, as in the post it is said that drupal & wordpress is working fine, means no mysql or apache2 issue, tried joomla 2.5.28 resulting in the same issue, so something wrong with joomla conf, no doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at the beginning, My php version is 7 and php7 compatible joomla versions are 3.5 and laters, that's why I was having these problems. So I just loaded the joomla 3.5.1 version and bingo. I discovered this in here https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Installing_Joomla in the references section.

Comment: I was trying to install the previous versions for stability, bad luck.